# How to type just in Persian in one of the Text-boxes

Tags: c#-4.0

I have several Text-boxes on the form. I want to type in one of them just in Persian. I found this code, but the first character is typed in English.

```
    private void txtBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        YourMethod();
    }

    private InputLanguage GetFarsiLanguage()
    {
        //Enumerate through InstalledInputLanguages which contains
        //all the keyboard layout you’ve installed in your windows.
        foreach (InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
        {
            if (lang.LayoutName.ToLower() == "farsi" || lang.LayoutName.ToLower() == "persian")
                return lang;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void YourMethod()
    {
        InputLanguage lang = GetFarsiLanguage();

        if (lang == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Farsi Language keyboard is not installed.");

        //Set the current language of the system to
        //the InputLanguage instance you need.
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;
    }

    private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        YourMethod();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described it sounds like the 'Enter' event isn't working for whatever reason. The txtBox_TextChanged event method will execute only after the first character has been entered. Hence the language will change after the first character.

To test this theory enter the following in the txtBox_Enter event method:

```
txtbox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

It will change the textbox red if the 'Enter' event executes.

If you can't get the 'Enter' event to work then try using the 'PreviewKeyDown' event.